# extract values from a query regex

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract the values ​​of a condition (WHERE) and did a regex, but I can not get the values ​​correctly.

```
//Patherns
$regex  = "/([a-zA-Z_]+)\s([\<\=\>\s]{0,4})\s+(\".*\")/";

//values ​​to be extracted
$string = 'idCidade >= "bla" OR idEstado="2" and idPais="3"'; 

//regex function
preg_match_all(
    $regex,
    $string,
    $output
);

//displays the result
echo '<pre>';print_r($output);



//incorrect output
Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => idCidade >= "bla" OR idEstado="2" and idPais="3"
    )

   [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => idCidade 
    )

   [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => >= 
    )

   [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => "bla" OR idEstado="2" and idPais="3"
    )
)
```

I need the regular expression to export the values ​​to an array like this;

```
//correct output
Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => idCidade >= "bla" OR idEstado="2" and idPais="3"
    )

   [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => idCidade
        [1] => idEstado
        [2] => idPais
    )

   [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => >=
        [1] => =
        [2] => =
    )

   [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => "bla"
        [1] => "2"
        [2] => "3"
    )
   [4] => Array
    (
        [0] => "OR"
        [1] => "AND"
        [2] => ""
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake was probably the `.*` which matches too much. You'd need to make it "ungreedy" with appending a question mark: `.*?`

I would however suggest this regex:

```
'/(OR|AND)?\s*(\w+)\s*([<=>!]+)\s*("[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'|\d+)/i'
```

This matches the boolean connector first and optionally, so that you get:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => OR
        [2] => and
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => idCidade
        [1] => idEstado
        [2] => idPais
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => >=
        [1] => =
        [2] => =
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => "bla"
        [1] => "2"
        [2] => "3"
    )
```

I've also made it work for SQL-compliant strings and decimals. But this is only borderline a job for regex. A real parser would be advisable. (Though I don't know your use case.)

Comment: I use this regex to treat the parameters passed to an existing API in my work, the person may seek specifying fields, values ​​and operators.

So I have to validate the data and verify that the fields are informed and are authorized to be searched.

ex. api.com/?search=title like blabla and id > 0

I had forgotten the operator "like" and changed the regex, I made the changes correctly?

    $regex  = '/(OR|AND)?\s*(\w+)\s*([<=>!]+|like)\s*("[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'|\d+)/i';

Comment: If you need the `LIKE` operator, then change the middle part of the regex to `([<=>!]+|like)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this. This outputs the exact result you need.

```
<?php  //Patherns
$regex  = '/([a-zA-Z_]+)\s*([>=<]*)\s*"([^"]*)"\s*(or|and)*/i';

//values to be extracted
$string = 'idCidade >= "bla" OR idEstado="2" and idPais="3"';

//regex function
preg_match_all(
    $regex,
    $string,
    $output
);

//displays the result
echo '<pre>';print_r($output);
```